# ADB bridge for Blackberry (incl. Monkeyrunner)

Tags: blackberry, adb

I have been using Monkeyrunner on adb for Android for a while, works great.

Is there an equivalent for Blackberry?  A tool to remote control Blackberrys for batch testing touch, drag, press-key etc?

Answer (score 1):

There are no such tool. But it's possible to automate user input for simulator (using fledgecontroller) or device (by own application with event injection).